# How to display data from API endpoint using Axios and React

Tags: reactjs, axios, crud

I'm currently running through this tutorial - https://appdividend.com/2018/11/11/react-crud-example-mern-stack-tutorial/#React_CRUD_Example

I've substituted in my own API and i've successfully managed to create new records. I'm now trying to view a list of all the records but getting the following error

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Here is the code (exact copy of tutorial code except API link)

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import axios from "axios";
    import TableRow from "./TableRow";

    export default class Index extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { address: [] };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        axios
          .get("http://localhost:6505/api/v1/Address")
          // .then(res => console.log(res))

          .then(response => {
            this.setState({ address: response.data });
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
      tabRow() {
        return this.state.address.map(function(object, i) {
          return ;
        });
      }

      render() {...}
```

If i add in the line that's commented out above '.then(res => console.log(res))', the error message no longer shows and the page renders but without any data - see screenshot below of page and console. I've highlighted the new error message and also highlighted where the data is that i want to display.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: where is the `tabRow` being invoked?

Comment: you can do this.setState({address:response.data.results

Comment: @nivendha Hi, the tabRow function is called after "render(){ return(", within a <tbody>

Comment: @lovepreetsingh thanks, this did cross my mind but didn't seem to make any difference. I'll leave it in the code though, as i have a feeling i may have more than one issue.

Comment: you are trying to map something that does not exist. Yo can set a initialState address=[]

Comment: yes you can set initial State  address:[]

Answer (score 1):

Your data is in `response.data.results` so change it to this and it will work.

Thanks

Comment: This seemed to fix the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.map` function is only available on array.

It looks like data isn't in the format you are expecting.

can you try with consoling `response.data` or `response.data.results`.

Can you replace `this.setState({ address: response.data });` with `this.setState({ address: response.data.results });`

Comment: Thanks, i've just updated code to `.then(res => console.log(res.data.results))` and results showed in the console as expected.

Comment: Then can you replace `this.setState({ address: response.data });` with `this.setState({ address: response.data.results });`

Comment: Oh i just removed the `.then(res => console.log(res.data.results))` line of code and saved the page, and the data is now showing! Thank you so much